# Azure App Service Kudu Continuous Deployment stopped working, not even showing latest commits

Tags: azure, continuous-deployment, azure-web-app-service, kudu

Two weeks ago I created 2 App Services, one is a Function App and the other is a PHP website... after having them created, I went to Deployment Center and configured this option to pull the code from an Azure GIT Repo and build & deploy the code using Kudu, everything was working as expected, whenever I made a code change and pushed it, Kudu was taking the latest commit, building and deploying the latest version...

Yesterday it stopped getting the latest commits from the Repo and by the time I tried to re-configure the setup to see if that helps it won't event display the commits anymore.

Here some screenshots showing the Web App and it's continuous deployment setup mapped to the Azure GIT Repo:

[WebApp Continuous Deployment Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTDBZ.jpg)

[Azure Repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkMgp.jpg)

Does anyone have faced this issue before? What could be potentially causing this situation? Could any quota limit be causing it?

NOTE: I have a Pay-as-you-go subscription.

Comment: Do you use slot by any chance?   We need more info about the site and relevant timeline to help pinpoint.  Please share sitename via https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly

Comment: Hi, @SuwatCh no slots are being used at all. Ok will share more details on the Kudu Wiki...

Comment: Was this ever resolved?